# How to change duration of a jQuery animation before it's completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Explanation**

I'm trying to change duration of a jQuery animation before it's completed, so I wrote the animation's code inside a function, where the duration is a variable. The animation has `queue: false` to start immediately when the duration's variable is changed and the function is called again with a button.

[image]

**The problem**:

When I click on the mentioned button the animation durantion changes, but when it finish it starts again with the previous duration.
Here is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/arglab/8yqaawdh/5/) with the code.

```js
var dur;

function foo(){
    $('.content').animate({width: '100%'},
    {
     duration: dur,
      easing: 'linear',
     queue: false,
      done: function(){
       $(this).css({width: '0%'});
        console.log('Prueba');
      }
    })
};

$('.start').click(function(){
    dur = 5 * 1000;
    foo();
});

$('.dur').click(function(){
   dur = 0.5 * 1000;
   foo();
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fdcfa2;
  border: 1px solid #b18963;
  color: #b18963;
}

button {
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 0;
  float: left;
  background: #d0fac0;
  border: 1px solid #6f9b5e;
  color: #6f9b5e;
}

button:nth-child(2) {
  background: #fff4a8;
  border: 1px solid #b1a763;
  color: #b1a763;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="start">Start</button>
<button class="dur">Duration to 0.5 s</button>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after the second animation has finished running, the first animation hasn't yet completed. Simply add a stop() to the previous animation, like this.

```
function foo(){
    $('.content').stop();  // stops the previous animation if running
    $('.content').animate({width: '100%'},
    {
        duration: dur,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
        done: function(){
          $(this).css({width: '0%'});
          console.log('Prueba');
        }
    })
};
```